# count nodes per property neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes, called Book. Each node have property Name (owner's name). It's not a lot of names, a lot of books. How to run aggregate query of all Names, and book quantity per Name?

```
Name Book_Count
Sam  55
John 12
```

Database version: 3.5

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I did manual approach because I have only few people:
 MATCH (n:Book) WHERE n.Name = "Sam" RETURN n count(n)
    ; Which is terrible solution for real life of course..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This will return the number nodes for each name:

```
MATCH (b:Book)
RETURN b.Name AS name, COUNT(*) AS book_count
```

Comment: It return me names in the left column but only zeroes in the right. Property Book_Count do not exists..

Comment: This worked:  
MATCH (b:Book) RETURN b.Name AS name, SUM(1) AS Book_Count

Comment: I had interpreted your question to mean that the `Book_Count` property existed. I have updated my answer to just count the number of nodes per name. Using `COUNT(*)` is more straightforward than `SUM(1)`, and may be slightly faster.